# Set serial stop bit count on Two in Windows 10 iot with RPi3 UART

Tags: uart, c++-cx, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I want to parameter my serial settings with 2 bit stop (in a UWP app) on a Raspberry Pi 3 to control a DMX512. My app is working and it works with a external FTDI, but not with the UART from the Raspberry Pi... I get a "parameter is incorrect" error when it execute the line with the stop bit parameter.

> ```
>         _serialPort->WriteTimeout = _timeOut;
>         _serialPort->ReadTimeout = _timeOut;
>         _serialPort->BaudRate = 250000;
>         _serialPort->Parity = Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialParity::None;
>         _serialPort->DataBits = 8;
>         _serialPort->StopBits = Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialStopBitCount::Two;
>         _serialPort->Handshake = Windows::Devices::SerialCommunication::SerialHandshake::None;
> ```

With Linux, I know that the UART of RPi3 supports 2 stop bits.

Someone has a solution or it's just because of Windows IOT ?

Thanks.

Comment: Every UART supports 2 stop bits.  The BaudRate is surely the real problem, 250000 is highly non-standard.  Start first at 9600.

Comment: Nope, even at 9600 it doesn't work, it's only the parity which cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

The exposed UART on the RPi3 doesn't support 2 stop bits, only 1 stop bit. Take a look at [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/4189) for citation and more details about the capabilities of the exposed UART.